# Adding a Convienience Method to Existing Class (Class Cast Exception)

Tags: java, android, oop, casting

Java/Android noob here (Still) I hoped you could help.

I was trying to add a small convenience method to get the number of time that has passed rather than the number of time since EPOCH.

So I tried to do this:

```
public class EasyLocation extends android.location.Location {

    ...

    public long getElapsedTime() {
        return getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

However when I tried to use it like in the code below which casts it to my Location class. I got a class cast exception. I've read up on it and I fully understand why it doesn't work. That's not the issue.

The issue is: it's not a train smash but I would like to have what is returned to have my method on it to make the rest of my code a bit cleaner. I can't figure out a way around it. Any ideas on how to do that?

```
lastNetworkLocation = (EasyLocation) locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Thanks,

Gerard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it like that. (A `Location` *is not* an `EasyLocation`.)

I believe what you're looking for is the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Java).

You would typically do something like this:

```
public class EasyLocation extends android.location.Location {

    public EasyLocation(Location loc) {
        // copy data from loc to this.
        super(loc);
    }
    ...

    public long getElapsedTime() {
        return getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

And instead of doing

```
lastNetworkLocation =
    (EasyLocation) locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(
                                              LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

you do

```
lastNetworkLocation =
    new EasyLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(
                                              LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
```

**Keep in mind though** that most people would probably say "Favor composition over inheritance", and go with

```
public class EasyLocation {

    Location loc;

    public EasyLocation(Location loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public long getElapsedTime() {
        return getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return loc;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would I use that?

lastNetworkLocation = new EasyLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));

Like this?

Comment: Awesome. I was nearly there! Thanks for that! :)

Comment: Hmmm Composition vs Inheritance. Gives me something to think about. Thanks for that. Composition does seem to be cleaner and make more sense in this case.